# How to implement partial swipe to show button and full swipe to dismiss in recycler view Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to implement partial swipe and full swipe functionality in recycler view item like what we see in notifications.

1. Partial swipe will show the button under the item.
2. Full swipe will dismiss the or perform some action.

Just like we can see in below image.

I tried to implement that using ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback, but not able to achieve the partial swipe with this.

Any idea how Android system is achieving this in the notification tray?

[image]

Implemented SwipeHelper like below using ItemTouchHelper. Complete swipe is happening but not partial swipe.
I tried to use the `getSwipeThreshold` in order to detect the swipe right after swiping item 10% by returning `0.1f` but still its swipe the item full not partial.

```
class SwipeHelper(
    dragDirs: Int, swipeDirs: Int
) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(dragDirs, swipeDirs) {

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {

    }

    override fun getSwipeThreshold(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Float {
        return 0.1f
    }

    override fun onChildDraw(
        c: Canvas,
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        dX: Float,
        dY: Float,
        actionState: Int,
        isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
    ) {

        val paint1 = Paint()
        paint1.color = Color.GREEN

        val paint2 = Paint()
        paint2.color = Color.BLUE

        //To draw button with background
        val rect1 = Rect(
            c.width + dX.toInt(),
            viewHolder.itemView.top,
            c.width + dX.toInt() + 100,
            viewHolder.itemView.bottom
        )

        val rect2 = Rect(
            rect1.right,
            viewHolder.itemView.top,
            c.width,
            viewHolder.itemView.bottom
        )

        c.drawRect(rect1, paint1)
        c.drawRect(rect2, paint2)

        if (abs(dX) < 200) {
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, 0F, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
        } else if (abs(dX) < c.width / 2) {
            super.onChildDraw(
                c,
                recyclerView,
                viewHolder,
                -200F,
                dY,
                actionState,
                isCurrentlyActive
            )
        } else {
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you might need to take a look at [ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper) and attach that into your recycler view

Comment: @segoSambel I added the sample code above which I tried for partial swipe, but no success.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to do that. I'm relatively new to Android development myself. However, I did manage to find a tutorial video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3w0rMx7J-QQ&ab_channel=EDMTDev) that might address your needs.

Comment: @segoSambel Doesn't solves the problem.